# VB Error with BMI calculations

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm having difficulty figuring out what's wrong with my BMI calculator. When I enter in a BMI that is less than 10 they show up as obese. If I enter anything above 10, it shows up as underweight. Any help would be appreciated.

This picture is an example of my problem:

[image]

Here is the code for my calculations:

```
Protected Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click

    Dim bmi As Double
    Dim bmiRounded As Double

    bmi = (txtWeight.Text * 703) / (txtHeight.Text * txtHeight.Text)

    bmiRounded = Math.Round(bmi, 1)
    lblBMI.Text = bmiRounded
    Select Case lblBMI.Text
        Case 0.0 To 18.5
            lblBMIResult.Text = "Underweight"
        Case 18.6 To 24.9
            lblBMIResult.Text = "Normal"
        Case 25.0 To 29.9
            lblBMIResult.Text = "Overweight"
        Case Is >= 30.0
            lblBMIResult.Text = "Obese"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't perform math on strings. i.e. `txtHeight.Text * txtHeight.Text` is invalid because that is a string. Similarly, `Select Case lblBMI.Text` is looking for a string, but your cases are ranges of Double. If you have something numeric,  hold it in a numeric variable. Put `Option Strict On` as the *first* line in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use numeric variables for numbers. Don't attempt math using string arguments. Put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file.

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
        Dim height As Double = Double.Parse(txtHeight.Text)
        Dim weight As Double = Double.Parse(txtWeight.Text)

        Dim bmi As Double = (weight * 703) / (height * height)
        Dim bmiRounded As Double = Math.Round(bmi, 1)

        lblBMI.Text = bmiRounded.ToString()

        Select Case bmiRounded
            Case 0.0 To 18.5
                lblBMIResult.Text = "Underweight"
            Case 18.6 To 24.9
                lblBMIResult.Text = "Normal"
            Case 25.0 To 29.9
                lblBMIResult.Text = "Overweight"
            Case Is >= 30.0
                lblBMIResult.Text = "Obese"
        End Select
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you. I made those changes and it is working correctly now

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code:

- It is better to convert the values from your `txtWeight.Text` and `txtHeight.Text` to numbers before you start the calculation instead relying on the compiler to implicitly convert them for you.
- Instead of multiplying the height by itself, you can use `height ^ 2`.
- Use the calculated `bmiRounded` instead of the `lblBMI.Text` in the `Select Case`.
- The first case can be written like `Case Is <= 18.5`, like you did with the last case.

Here is an updated version with all above recommendations:

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    Dim bmi As Double
    Dim bmiRounded As Double

    Dim height As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtHeight.Text)
    Dim weight As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtWeight.Text)

    bmi = (weight * 703) / (height ^ 2)
    bmiRounded = Math.Round(bmi, 1)
    lblBMI.Text = bmiRounded

    Select Case bmiRounded
        Case Is <= 18.5
            lblBMIResult.Text = "Underweight"
        Case 18.6 To 24.9
            lblBMIResult.Text = "Normal"
        Case 25.0 To 29.9
            lblBMIResult.Text = "Overweight"
        Case Is >= 30.0
            lblBMIResult.Text = "Obese"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Note: I assumed that you will enter the height and weight as integers, but if you want to enter them with decimal point then convert to `Double` instead of `Integer`:

```
Dim height As Double = Double.Parse(txtHeight.Text)
Dim weight As Double = Double.Parse(txtWeight.Text)
```

Comment: Thank you! Using bmiRounded instead of lblBMI.text worked!